# Decimal to binary homework in Java

Tags: java, binary

I have a homework to do a decimal to binary conversation. This is the code I have:

```
int num = 0;
int temp = 0;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
num = sc.nextInt();

//System.out.print(""+ num%2+ (num%2)%2);
while(num != 0) {
  temp = num;
  System.out.print(""+(int) temp % 2);
  num = num / 2;    
}
```

It is working fine, but it giving me the output as LSB and not as MSB.

For example:

```
35
110001
```

but I need it to be `100011`.

I cannot use any function or method to reverse it. I know I can put it in an array, string or whatever and do some magic. But I can use only the `while` loop, modulo and print.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Is intermediate storage of each binary digit allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't output each digit as you find them. Build your output incrementally and then print it at the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int num = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            num = sc.nextInt();

    int place = 1;
    int output = 0;

    while(num != 0) {
       temp = num % 2;
       num = num / 2;    

       output += (place*temp);
       place *=10;
    }

    System.out.print(""+output);
}
```

You may need to modify this to handle large or negative numbers.

Comment: what is mean += and *= is like output=output+(place*temp)?

Comment: @OfirAttia yes, that is exactly it.

Comment: so what you did? the place is always 10, but when you * it in 0 is 0 but what you * it in 1 it 10 , i dont understand the logic here sorry

Comment: you moved the number to the left?

Comment: `place` represents the location where each binary digit is stored in the output. for the first iteration it is stored in the one's place (`place ==1`). the second digit is stored in the ten's place (`place == 10`). the third is stored in the hundreds place (`place == 100`). ect..

Answer (score 4):

Instead of starting at the bottom bit, you can start at the top bit.

```
int i = 35;

// find where the top bit is.
int shift = 0;
while (i >>> (shift + 1) > 0) shift++;

// print from the top bit down
while (shift >= 0)
    System.out.print((i >>> shift--) & 1);
```

prints i = 35

```
100011
```

prints for i = -35

```
11111111111111111111111111011101
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to convert it to a long first.  Since java doesn't have `uint` .  For large cases of i

Comment: Good answer, but might not be appropriate for a homework answer.

Comment: @ColinD I would imagine since OP can only use modulo arithmetic to solve this, it may be the solution that is desired.

Comment: A working, concise, and magic-looking solution to a homework task. Exactly what I'd rather never receive if I were a beginner.

Comment: @9000 I would hardly call this magic, it is fundamentally no different than modulo arithmetic.  Which the OP has to use.

Comment: @Woot4Moo maybe it was just my experience, but bit shifting was one of the last things I learned in school. I would think the 'expected' solution would involve intermediate storage, but then again, the homework assignment in full was not posted so I am just speculating.

Comment: @OfirAttia you should try running it.  The above solution will fail in large cases of i, which is why I suggested using a long

Comment: You can not use arrays, strings, functions, or any other form of code that has not been learned
Classroom. Use one of the forms of the code may result in a reduction in grade work.

Comment: @Woot4Moo It prints as I would expect for negative numbers.

Comment: @ColinD Interesting, in my studies one of the first things we had to learn was binary arithmetic.

Comment: @OfirAttia This is intended to give you any idea of what you can do.  Only you know what you have learnt in class.

Comment: @Woot4Moo It is significant that I used `>>>` instead of `>>` ;)

Comment: what i have learned in class is while,for,and print. if you really want to know, i sent mail to my teacher and asked him if i can use some array or string and he told me no. and for my aknowledge i will read about >>> operator or how its called becuase i didnt used it

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ah yes I missed the third `>` +1 to you

Comment: Ok, since it is your homework, you should be able to translate this into the functionality you know. Is there anything specific you have having difficulty with?

Comment: amm, i didnt understand what you did there. becuase i dont see any mod here or something. what is mean >>> , anyway thank you ! i will read about that

Comment: It is similar to `/ Math.pow(2, shift)` except its is "unsigned" which means negative numbers are treated as large positive numbers.

Comment: @OfirAttia That would start at the bottom, you need to start at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers are really right-to-left (guess why they call it 'Arabic numerals'?). The least significant digit of a number is its *last* digit.

You generate binary digits from least significant to most significant. You have to store them and then print in reverse order, from most significant to least significant.

Try using a `List<Integer>` or an `int[]` for this.

Answer (score 0):

One work around could be as below:

```
  int indx = 0;
  if(num<0){
      indx =31;
      num = Integer.MAX_VALUE+num+2;
  }else{
      while((int)Math.pow(2, indx) <= num){
           indx++; 
      }
       indx--;//get the highest index
  }
   System.out.print(""+1);//print the highest bit
   num = num % (int)Math.pow(2, indx);
   indx--;
   //print the bits right to left
   for(int i = indx; i >=0; i--){
     if(Math.abs(num)<2){
       System.out.print(""+num);
     }else if((int)Math.pow(2, i) >= num){
        System.out.print(""+0);
     }else{
       num = num % (int)Math.pow(2, i); //get the remaining value
       System.out.print(""+1);
     }
   }
```